# I wanna read each cell of pandas df one after another and do some calculation on them

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna read each cell of pandas df one after another and do some calculation on them, but I have a problem using dictionaries or lists. for example, I wanna check the Ith cell whether the outdoor door temperature is more than X and also humidity is more/less than Y!then do a special calculation for the row.

here is the body of loaded df:

```
  data=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Thesis/DS1.xlsx - Sheet1.csv')
  data=data.drop(columns=["Date","time","real feel","Humidity","indoor temp"])
  print(data)
```

and here is the data:

```
    outdoor temp  Unnamed: 6  Humidity Estimation: (poly3)
   0              26         NaN                       64.1560
   1              25         NaN                       68.6875
   2              25         NaN                       68.6875
   3              24         NaN                       72.4640
   4              24         NaN                       72.4640
  ..            ...         ...                           ...
 715            35         NaN                       22.5625
 716            33         NaN                       28.1795
 717            32         NaN                       32.3680
 718            31         NaN                       37.2085
 719            30         NaN                       42.5000

 [720 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function and then use .apply() to use the function on each row. You can edit temp and humid to your desired values. If you want to reference a specific row then just use data[row index]. I am not sure what calculation you want to do but I just added one to the value.

```
def calculation(row, temp, humid):
    if row["outdoor temp"] > temp:
        row["outdoor temp"] += 1
    if row["humidity"] > humid:
        row["humidity"] += 1
data = data.apply(lambda row : calculation(row, temp, humid), axis = 1)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. it's worth mentioning that i want a put an else in the if loop like this:
def calculation(row, temp, humid):
    if row["outdoor temp"] > 37:
      "outdoor temp" ==28
      else:
      row["outdoor temp"] += 1
to check if the row was equal to X, set the row equal to Y!
but it gets syntax error after putting else.
do you have any advise for me?

Comment: Can you be more specific and show me an example of your code?

Comment: Sure
here is the code i want to implemet:
if vTemperature >= 80:
  vFeelsLike = -42.379 + 2.04901523*vTemperature + 10.14333127*vRelativeHumidity - .22475541*vTemperature*vRelativeHumidity - .00683783*vTemperature*vTemperature - .05481717*vRelativeHumidity*vRelativeHumidity + .00122874*vTemperature*vTemperature*vRelativeHumidity + .00085282*vTemperature*vRelativeHumidity*vRelativeHumidity - .00000199*vTemperature*vTemperature*vRelativeHumidity*vRelativeHumidity
  and i want to put my df columns instead of these parameters.

Comment: What you could do is create a separate column and apply the same function. For example, data["new temp"] = data.apply(lambda row : calculation(row, temp, humid), axis = 1) and you change the function so it matches with your parameters